# How to write a xpath based on the both conditions with Plan Documents and PDF Languages? Like this one: //span[text()='"+filePath+"']/

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, xpath, xpath-1.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FJ0A.png)

I need the xpath like this one: Like this one: //span[text()='"+filePath+"']/..    so that I can use 2 String values for the condition.

```html
<table class="cmp-filtertable__results-table d-none d-md-table" xpath="1">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="cmp-filtertable__results-table--heading">
                    <th>Plan Documents</th><th>PDF Languages</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                <td>Summary of Benefits (includes a pre-enrollment checklist)</td>
                <td><div class="cmp-filtertable__results-table--link__pdf">
             <a href="/documents/individual/2021/summaryofbenefits/SB_2021_H0523_002_EN.pdf" target="_blank" aria-describedby="opensNewWindow">
               <span class="link__digitaldownload">
                  English
                <span>
                <span class="sr-only">  Summary of Benefits (includes a pre-enrollment checklist) PDF</span>
              </span></span></a>
          </div><div class="cmp-filtertable__results-table--link__pdf">
             <a href="/documents/individual/2021/spanish/summaryofbenefits/SB_2021_H0523_002_SP.pdf" target="_blank" aria-describedby="opensNewWindow">
               <span class="link__digitaldownload">
                  Español
                <span>
                <span class="sr-only">  Summary of Benefits (includes a pre-enrollment checklist) PDF</span>
              </span></span></a>
          </div></td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td>Evidence of Coverage (coverage details)</td>
                <td><div class="cmp-filtertable__results-table--link__pdf">
             <a href="/documents/individual/2021/eoc/EOC_2021_H0523_002_EN.pdf" target="_blank" aria-describedby="opensNewWindow">
               <span class="link__digitaldownload">
                  English
                <span>
                <span class="sr-only">  Evidence of Coverage (coverage details) PDF</span>
              </span></span></a>
          </div><div class="cmp-filtertable__results-table--link__pdf">
             <a href="/documents/individual/2021/spanish/eoc/EOC_2021_H0523_002_SP.pdf" target="_blank" aria-describedby="opensNewWindow">
               <span class="link__digitaldownload">
                  Español
                <span>
                <span class="sr-only">  Evidence of Coverage (coverage details) PDF</span>
              </span></span></a>
          </div></td>
```

This is the website: https://www.aetnamedicare.com/en/for-members/plan-documents-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Set an [XPath variable](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Basics):

```
String path = /* ... */;

QName pathVarName = new QName("path");

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(name -> {
    if (pathVarName.equals(name)) {
        return path;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});

Object match = xpath.evaluate("//span[text()=$path]", document);
```